# Which one is correct preposition and why?

Tags: prepositions

Don't find fault "in" others or Don't find fault "with" others.
Which of the preposition is correct in this sentence?

Comment: _In_ wouldn't be 'incorrect', but the usual expression is _find fault with_.

Comment: "Usual expression"? I'd say both are equally correct, one is not 'better' than the other, but they mean different things… I'm just struggling to nail it in a way to tell someone else ;)

Comment: Please search for "find fault" within two words of "others"; I'm sure that you will find useful results. For example, [Google ngrams' search help](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info) explains how to do so and even lets you require that the intervening word be a preposition.

Comment: Both are fine but I think don't find fault with is more common. Neither of these are super common phrases though.